# different cases differentiate and link them

Tags: xslt

I've the below XML.

```
<orderedlist type="manual">
<item num="1."><para>identify the issues in dispute;</para></item>
<item num="1.1"><para>explore and generate options;</para></item>
<item num="1.1.1"><para>communicate with one another; and/or</para></item>
<item num="(i)"><para>copy of the cancellation of employment pass; and</para></item>
<orderedlist>
```

here i want to translate all the `.` to `-` in `item-num` and surround them with a different tag, where there is some number or period after `.` previously I've received a solution and I've used `not(ends-with(./@num,'.'))`. That worked fine till some point, recently I've came across a situation(4th `item num` in the above XML) where in the `item num` has values like `(i), i, a, a)`, and these also satisfy the condition and are getting the new `tag`. below is my XSL template.

```
    <xsl:template name="orderedlist" match="orderedlist">
        <ol class="eng-orderedlist orderedlist">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </ol>
    </xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="item">
    <xsl:call-template name="paran"></xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template name="paran">
<xsl:apply-templates select="./para/node()[1][self::page]" mode="first"/>
      <li class="item">
      <div class="para">

<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="not(ends-with(./@num,'.'))">
         <a name="{translate(./@num,'.','-')}"/>
    <span class="phrase">
    <xsl:value-of select="./@num"></xsl:value-of>
    </span>  
</xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="./@num">
    <span class="item-num">
    <xsl:value-of select="./@num"></xsl:value-of>
    </span>  
</xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>

   <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </div>
      </li>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="page[not(preceding-sibling::node()[not(self::text()) or normalize-space()])]"/>
```

here i don't want `phrase` around other numbers than i format `X.X` `X.X.X`.

you can find a demo of this issue [here](http://xsltransform.net/pPqsHSV).

please let me know how can i fix it.

Thanks

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: You've asked a number of very similar questions in the past couple of weeks.  Since you've indicated in the past that you are using XSLT 2.0 I would once again recommend what I suggested in a comment to [my answer to one of your previous questions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24040621/592139) - the structure you're looking for can be compactly represented as a regular expression, so you can use the `matches` function to test for it.

Comment: Hi @helderdarocha, the expected output is apart from `item num` in the format `X.X` or `X.X.X`, all other `item-num` should be in surrounded by `<span class="item-num">` but not `<span class="phrase">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you need to add a check on whether the **num** attribute contains a full-stop in the first place

```
 <xsl:when test="contains(@num, '.') and not(ends-with(./@num,'.'))">
```

i.e. **@num** contains a full-stop, but not one at the end.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest you do it this way:

```
<xsl:template match="item">
    <!-- do one thing here  -->
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="item [not(ends-with(@num, '.'))] [not (translate(@num, '.123456789', ''))]">
<!-- do another thing here  -->
</xsl:template>
```

--
Doing the predicate by regex as suggested by Ian Roberts would probably be more elegant.